# My backgrounds looks wrong on mobile and tablet, what to do?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad, background-size

My backgrounds looks totally wrong on my Ipad and Iphone, when I test it.
I have search here on stackoverflow for my problem, but without luck!
I know that "background-size:cover" is the problem, but i don't know how to fix it.

```
#home, #music, #videos, #tourplan, #facebook, #profile, #downloads {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#home, #videos, #downloads {
    height: 100vh;
}
#music, #tourplan, #facebook, #profile {
    min-height: 100vh;
    height:auto;    
}
```

Comment: try `brackground-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: could be your `vh` units - IOS reports buggy behaviour - http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Comment: Thats correct Pete, any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: You can try to "hack" around it using CSS media queries

Comment: Bytheway http://i.imgur.com/GrdT0qL.png???

Answer (score 0):

I am agree that "background-size: cover" is not working properly in Ipad and Iphone due to small width. So, If you have on problem, you could use any background color (according to your choice) for Ipad and Iphone.

```
/* Ipad Layout: 480px. */

@media only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width: 767px){ {
    #home, #music, #videos, #tourplan, #facebook, #profile, #downloads {
    background: #ddd; /* Just as an example */
    }
}

/* Iphone Layout: 360px. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    #home, #music, #videos, #tourplan, #facebook, #profile, #downloads {
    background: #ddd; /* Just as an example */
    }   
}
```

If you like to use different background colors instead of different background images, you could use this code:

```
#home {
          background: #ddd; /* Just as an example */
}
#music {
       background: #eee; /* Just as an example */
}
#videos {
        background: #fff; /* Just as an example */
}
#tourplan {
          background: #000; /* Just as an example */
}
#facebook {
          background: #00ff00; /* Just as an example */
}
#profile {
         background: #ff0000; /* Just as an example */
}
#downloads {
           background: #0000ff; /* Just as an example */
}
```

In that case, you need to put this code your particular CSS media queries areas like . You need to change the element color such as text color etc. To see the site like this, please visit this link: http://www.ollo.com.br/m/

Keep well.